# Debugging on a Surface Tablet of UWP Application

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, surface-pro

I want to debug Microsoft UWP Application on my Surface tablet by connecting USB cable the way we do in Android and iOS development. Currently I am packaging the App and downloading and installing App on surface table which is very time consuming.
I have already gone through this post https://tomsoderling.github.io/Wired-Debugging-on-Surface/ but seems not practical in terms of development

Can anyone help?

Comment: Great you posted the link _what you tried reading already_  This is your research part we require here in SO. It shows us where you stuck, that you tried to solve your problem. Only then we can support you. But you have to code yourself, practice! Only then you will learn and make progress. We will not do the work for you, we will not code for you. So please always provide a [example] that shows __what is not practical ...__. Show __your terms of development__: What have you tried⁉️

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio lets you to deploy and debug your app remotely on other computers/devices. No cable needed. Details are documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2019

Comment: [Leading by Example](https://www.amanet.org/articles/leading-by-example/) could teach the OP how and why to [format links with a proper label](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315992/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links?r=SearchResults) (other than: `here`)  The only part of your answer that didactically convinces me is: _vague explanation_ to solve an equally _vague described_ problem 